# How to produce a interpolated smooth 3d plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This plot is created by `Mathematica`:

```
ls = Table[Sinc[x*y], {x, -5, 5, 0.2}, {y, -5, 5, 0.2}];
ListPlot3D[ls, InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

How to create a plot like this in MatLab?

Here is my try so far:

```
>> x=linspace(-5.,5.,51);
>> y=linspace(-5.,5.,51);
>> [x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
>> z=sinc(x.*y);
>> surf(x,y,z)
>> shading interp
```

It looks like very different, especially the details of the ripples. Is it possible to make a plot like the Mathematica one, especially the smoothness, shadows ?

[image]

Comment: Good question. Allow me to just mention a Free Software, Open Source alternative to these two proprietary programs: GNU Octave. As to "Mathematica" and "MATLAB", I have no idea.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I'm getting a [nice plot](http://i.imgur.com/WzFHUgn.png)...

Comment: @EitanT I'm using 2012a on Mac. But in your plot there are still some wrinkles and lines in the wall.

Comment: The lines on the wall are removeable gridlines. Regarding the wrinkles, that's indeed a matter of better interpolation, which your code didn't specify.

Comment: @EitanT sorry for the confusion, I just mean the wrinkles, and the gutters, not the gridlines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to create nice lighting and shadows, you need to add a light to your plot, and add some sort of face lighting. If the resolution is too low, then you will end up with a somewhat ragged plot, since the 'interp' style shading uses linear interpolation. For example

```
n = 51;
x=linspace(-5., 5., n);
y=linspace(-5., 5., n);
[x, y]=meshgrid(x, y);
sinc = @(x) sin(x)./x;
z=sinc(x.*y);
z(isnan(z)) = 1;
surf(x, y, z, 'LineStyle', 'none', 'FaceColor', 'interp')
colormap(cool)
camlight right
set(gca, 'CameraPosition', [45 35 9.8])
```

which produces the following

[image]

Note that how smooth the surface appears is related to `n`. Larger values of `n` will increase the smoothness of the surface.

If the data you produce is expensive to create, you can increase the resolution by using a more advanced form of interpolation than linear, as follows

```
n = 51;
x=linspace(-5., 5., n);
y=linspace(-5., 5., n);
[x, y]=meshgrid(x, y);
sinc = @(x) sin(x)./x;
z=sinc(x.*y);
z(isnan(z)) = 1;

nn = 401;
xi = linspace(-5.0, 5.0, nn);
yi = xi;
[xi, yi] = meshgrid(xi, yi);
zi = interp2(x, y, z, xi, yi, 'spline');
surf(xi, yi, zi, 'LineStyle', 'none', 'FaceColor', 'interp')
colormap(cool)
camlight right
set(gca, 'CameraPosition', [45 35 9.8])
```

which produces the following image

[image]

See the following help pages for more details

- [Surface Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface_props.html)
- [camlight](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camlight.html)
- [Coloring Mesh and Surface Plots](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/coloring-mesh-and-surface-plots.html)
- [interp2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)

Comment: Thanks. But could you try my function, yours function seems already very smooth.

Comment: I changed my answer to use your function instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I think my problem is how to plot the existing matrix, not to increase the number of points in the matrix, because in my research that matrix is produced using other very expensive program.

Comment: you can fix this by interpolating your data. I've included an example in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest try surf/surfl and try turn on/off lighting. Initial camera position is also important because I use "headlight" cam.

```
x=linspace(-5.,5.,51);
y=linspace(-5.,5.,51);
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z=sinc(x.*y);
surfl(x,y,z) %surf(x, y, z)
shading interp
colormap cool
%camlight headlight
%lighting gouraud
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I've checked your answer, but on my computer it didn't produce a smooth interpolated plot like in the question (I'm not sure wether is the version problem).

Comment: I liked the output of "surf"+"lighting on". The other question that you needed reinterplotation, I didn't guess that